# Probabilty that none of n i.i.d uniform samples from R^2 are larger in both coordinates than first.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, order-statistics

I am randomly sampling n elements from a square within R^2. They are independently uniformly distributed. What is the probability that for any arbitrarily but fixed previously selected sample index, it is true that no other sample is greater in both coordinates? I do not know anything else about the preselected sample.

This is part of a larger problem which I have reduced to this question, I can explain it should it be neccessary.

Comment: What is the sample index?

Comment: I was hoping that the result would be the same for every index, since they are i.i.d, there should be no a priori difference between them, but let's say it's the first.

Comment: Ah, by sample index you mean like the $j$th sample, for a specific fixed $j$.  Then yeah, they are iid.  You can set up an integral for the $j$th sample being $(x,y)$ and integrate over all $(x,y)$, but it's kinda messy.

Comment: Aha!  Turns out we don't need calculus after all, but pls tell me first -- where does the problem come from?  Depending on whether this is work, homework, exam etc, we can give you different amounts of info / hints.

Comment: I am developing a software for a bioinformatics research project in which I have implemented a kind of weird data structure whose efficiency I'm trying to evaluate. Consider that these samples are drawn one after another. After every draw I need to keep only those samples in storage which are not less in both coordinates than any other one sample. I am trying to figure out the expected number of items stored after n samples have been drawn. If I'm not mistaken, the probability I am looking for here times the number of samples should yield this expected value.

Comment: @antkam With the help of WolframAlpha, I might have solved that integral. Apparently WolframAlpha thinks it should be H(n)/n where H(n) is the n-th harmonic number. Could that be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When has Wolfram Alpha been wrong?  :) Yes the answer is $H_n / n$ where $H_n$ is the $n$th Harmonic number.

(I am curious how you asked WA.  Did you type in the integral?  Do you mind sharing the link?)

Consider all $n$ different $x$-coordinates of the $n$ points.  Since there is perfect symmetry between the points, your specific point $P = (x_P, y_P)$ is equally likely to have the smallest $x$, or second smallest, or third smallest, etc., up to being the largest.  I.e., let $M$ be the number of points whose $x$-coordinate exceeds $x_P$, then $M$ is uniform among $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, n-1\}$, each choice with probability $1/n$.

Now, when will point $P$ meet your criterion?  Consider the set containing $P$ and all $M$ points whose $x$-coordinate exceeds $x_P$ (the other points don't matter any more).  Among this set of $M+1$ points, point $P$ must have the highest $y$-coordinate for $P$ to meet your criterion.  Due to symmetry between these $M+1$ points, the probability is $1/(M+1)$.  (Here we used the fact $x$ and $y$ coordinates are independent.)  Therefore:

$$Prob(P \text{ meets your criterion}) = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \frac1{m+1} Prob(M=m) = \frac1n \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \frac1{m+1}  = {H_n \over n}$$

And you are right: linearity of expectation implies that the expected number of points meeting your criterion (i.e. which you need to store) is $H_n$.

Comment: I let the domain of the samples be [0,1] in both coordinates to have a constant density =1 for each sample. The probability of the event for a given (x,y) is (x+y-xy)^(n-1). Then I constructed the double integral of this over the domain. Solved the inner integral through substitution and put this into WA: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+%28-1+%2B+y%5Ea%29%2F%28a+%28-1+%2B+y%29%29+dy%2C+a%3D100

I had to specify n, otherwise it returned a more complicated term involving the hypergeometric function.

Your answer is much simpler though, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  I was doing much more complicated combinatorial counting which led to the correct answer $H_n / n$, and then I thought there must be a simpler argument if the answer is so simple.  Fun problem!

Comment: One small correction: The sums' ranges are off by one.

Comment: Fixed, thank you!